# Speeding up queries subject to VPD policy

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, row-level-security, vpd

I'm currently applying this predicate on a VPD policy:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION limit_table(
  schema_p   IN VARCHAR2,
  table_p    IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  pred VARCHAR2 (400);
BEGIN 
  pred := ' ((select count(granted_role) from user_role_privs where (granted_role = Jurisdiction OR granted_role = Business_Domain))  = 2)  OR
                  ((Jurisdiction = '''' OR Jurisdiction IS NULL) AND (Business_Domain = '''' OR Business_Domain IS NULL)) '  ; 
  RETURN pred;
END;
/
```

What it does is checking if the user has roles matching both the Jurisdiction and Business domain (of the table I assigned the policy to) and also if they are null or empty. In those cases, the row is whitelisted and the user can see it.
The problem is that this policy slows down the queries made by the users affected by it more than I would like. The bottleneck is the first clause of the predicate. I also tried with *dba_role_privs* which allegedly should be faster but performance stays the same.

I followed what this page suggests
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:484621563404
but unfortunately I'm not able to try the third method because my client tells me the sys.user$ table does not exist.

Also tried indexes on jurisdiction and business domain and they don't improve anything.

Originally, the predicate was

```
pred := '(
  (
    (
      (Business_Domain IS NULL OR 
        Business_Domain = '''' OR 
        Business_Domain IN (select granted_role from user_role_privs)
      ) 
      AND  
      (Jurisdiction IS NULL OR 
        Jurisdiction = '''' OR 
        Jurisdiction IN (select granted_role from user_role_privs) 
      )
    )  )
 )'; 
 RETURN pred;
```

But it was way slower.

Does anyone know ways I can speed up that predicate? Thanks.

Comment: Wild guess, but would rewriting it as `sys_context('SYS_SESSION_ROLES', jurisdiction) = 'TRUE' and sys_context('SYS_SESSION_ROLES', business_domain) = 'TRUE'` or perhaps more concisely `'TRUE' = all (...)` be more efficient than counting a subquery? I'm not clear what the `''''` expression is meant to do so that might need some `nvl`s. Obviously nothing can be equal to `''`.

Comment: How often are users assigned or de-assigned roles?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - unfortunately it is not obvious. Many people don't know that Oracle treats empty string as NULL, because many other database flavours distinguish between them.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I'm trying your suggestion and it seems fast, problem is my assigned roles only show up in user_role_privs and dba_role_privs, not in session_roles. Do you know how I can grant a role so that it also appears in session roles? Right now I'm using "GRANT role_x TO user_y"

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the suggestion by the very kind @WilliamRobertson, I switched the predicate to:

```
' ((sys_context(''SYS_SESSION_ROLES'', jurisdiction) = ''TRUE'' AND sys_context(''SYS_SESSION_ROLES'', business_domain) = ''TRUE'')  OR
              ((Jurisdiction = '''' OR Jurisdiction IS NULL) AND (Business_Domain = '''' OR Business_Domain IS NULL))) '  ;
```

This required, however, to make the roles granted by the users defaults, otherwise they would not appear in the session_roles. I did it with:

```
ALTER USER <name> DEFAULT ROLE ALL;
```

Comment: Glad that worked, upvoted. By the way, nothing can be `= ''` in Oracle SQL, as it has no concept of 'empty string' as distinct from null string. Maybe that simplifies your solution.

Comment: Will check! The bottleneck was actually in the query, not the logical formulas